# What is the Mac download site for the PLUG-IN version of Eclipse PHP Development Tools (PDT)?

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin

What is the Mac download site for the PLUG-IN version of Eclipse PHP Development Tools (PDT)?  I have Adobe CS5 Flash Builder on Eclipse and would like to use the Galileo php as a plug-in.
Thank you!

Comment: Updated my entry, guess I didn't post the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it from the Eclipse Update Site.

> Help > Install New Software

Set "Work with:" to --All Available Sites--, and type PDT in for your filter text.

EDIT: If it doesn't work with all available sites, checking on my mac shows that it is under.
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

Called PHP Development Tools (PDT)

Comment: Yes, I went Help> install new software etc. But need the correct URL because it doesn't recognize it on my mac.